# Move layout above soft keyboard like edit contacts app

Tags: android, layout, android-softkeyboard

I have the following layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/name"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="@string/name"
                                android:inputType="text"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/address_name"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="@string/address_name"
                                android:inputType="text"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/address"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="@string/address"
                                android:inputType="text"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/street"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="@string/street"
                                android:inputType="text"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/city"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="@string/city"
                                android:inputType="text"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/state"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="@string/state"
                                android:inputType="text"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/postal_code"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="@string/postal_code"
                                android:inputType="text"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/landmark"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="@string/landmark"
                                android:inputType="text"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>            

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I enter data, the soft keyboard hides the fields. I tried setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in manifest with various setting like `adjustNothing, adjustResize` etc. These settings never worked.

I want to have the fields scrollable, above the soft keyboard. So data can be entered like default edit contact app in Android.

Tried with Android 5.1

Comment: try don't give any criteria in manifest. just leave it in manifest.

Comment: without any criteria also not working